# How to setup with vim YCM

Tags: vim, premake, youcompleteme

i want to move from using CMake to Premake for my current project, but im usig vim and the YCM plugin which is really great for making my setup like an IDE. However, the plugin needs compilation flags file which is produced when running CMake. Is there something for Premake to generate a file like that as well?

Answer (score 0):

Premake does not do this in its current state (alpha 13). If you have some insights as to what is necessary for getting it to work, the best thing to do would be to submit a [ticket](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues) in the issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, if your new build system does not generate that compilation flags file (yet), you'll need to maintain your own (hand-crafted) one. You can find an example at https://github.com/Valloric/ycmd/blob/0e999dbee209ea79a522259816ce3a68b7d6cddc/examples/.ycm_extra_conf.py.

I would advice to have (at least) one per project rather than one generic one in your $HOME.

Although I have to admit, that it would be beneficial to get it created and in sync with the actual build system, I don't find it too troublesome to maintain it manually. At the end of the day it only contains the *C++ standard* you want to use, a set of *preprocessor symbols* and a set of both system and user *include directories*.